# What is the difference between these two module definitions?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Regarding the Phoenix Framework: I was just wondering what the difference is between writing

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  # some code
end
```

and just

```
defmodule User do
  # some code
end
```

later on it would be easier to just write User.function than MyApp.User.function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is namespacing you module to avoid clashes. Imagine a scenario where you call your module `User` and then user a library called user which also defines a `User` module. You would have a collision.

You can [alias](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) in modules that use your `User` module though:

```
defmodule MyApp.SomeModule do
  alias MyApp.User

  def foo do
    User.some_function
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be applied with the concept of [nesting](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#nesting) in elixir. Often you would like group a certain modules according to their functionality or just for the sake of naming convinence. 
Here is a straight example from the docs

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmodule Bar do
  end
end
```

Which is same as

```
defmodule Elixir.Foo do
  defmodule Elixir.Foo.Bar do
  end
  alias Elixir.Foo.Bar, as: Bar
end
```

It is important to note that in Elixir,there is no need to define the **Outer** module to able to use `Outer.Inner` module name, as the language translates all module names to atoms anyway. You can define arbitrarily-nested modules without defining any module in the chain (e.g., Foo.Bar.Baz without defining Foo or Foo.Bar first).

A solid example is available at the [elixir docs](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#nesting).